# ValueError: Value Tensor("normalize_element/component_0:0", shape=(), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0) has insufficient rank for batching

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to predict with an estimator, but I get this error:

```
ValueError: Value Tensor("normalize_element/component_0:0", shape=(), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0) has insufficient rank for batching.
```

```
pred = {"Team1":10764 ,
"Team1Rank":51,
"Team1Prediction":17,
"Team2":8211,
"Team2Rank":81,
"Team2Prediction":1,
"Odds1":1.3,
"Odds2":3.2,
"BestOf":3
}

def pred_fn(features, batch_size=960):
    db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features))).batch(batch_size)
    return db

predictions = classifier.predict(
    input_fn=lambda: pred_fn(pred))

print(list(predictions))
```

I am following the standard guide, trying different things but nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change fixed the issue

```
db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features))).batch(batch_size)
```

To

```
db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(dict(features)).batch(batch_size)
```